# Material UI Textfield does not do linebreak on complex string

Tags: json, reactjs, newline, textfield

I am trying to get some data from a MySQL query to be output nicely in a Material UI Textfield. My Textfield looks like this:

```
<TextField
  className={classes.output}
  InputProps={{
    classes: {
      input: classes.code,
    },
  }}
  multiline
  rows={20}
  variant="outlined"
  value={trace}
/>
```

The trace variable looks like this, a complex string with a lot of escapes:

```
[
  "select * from person",
  "{\n  \"steps\": [\n    {\n      \"join_preparation\": {\n        \"select#\": 1,\n        \"steps\": 
[\n          {\n            \"expanded_query\": \"/* select#1 */ select `person`.`name` AS `name` from `person`\"
\n          }\n        ]\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"join_optimization\": {\n        \"select#\": 
1,\n        \"steps\": [\n          {\n            \"table_dependencies\": [\n    
          {\n                \"table\": \"`person`\",\n                \"row_may_be_null\": false,\n  
              \"map_bit\": 0,\n                \"depends_on_map_bits\": [\n
                ]\n              }\n            ]\n          },\n          {\n            \"rows_estimation\": [\n              {\n  
              \"table\": \"`person`\",\n                \"table_scan\":
 {\n                  \"rows\": 2,\n                  \"cost\": 0.25\n                }\n
              }\n            ]\n          },\n          {\n            \"considered_execution_plans\":
 [\n              {\n                \"plan_prefix\": [\n                ],\n                \"table\": \"`person`\",\n                \
"best_access_path\"
: {\n     
             \"considered_access_paths\": [\n                    {\n                      \"rows_to_scan\": 2,\n                      \
"access_type\": \"scan\",\n                      \"resulting_rows\": 2,\n                      \"cost\": 0.45,\n                      \
"chosen\": true\n                    }\n                  ]\n                },\n                \
"condition_filtering_pct\": 100,\n                \"rows_for_plan\": 2,\n                \"cost_for_plan\": 0.45,\n                \
"chosen\": true\n              }\n            ]\n          },\n          {\n            \
"attaching_conditions_to_tables\": {\n              \"original_condition\": null,\n              \"attached_conditions_computation\": [\n              ],\n              \
"attached_conditions_summary\": [\n                {\n                  \"table\": \"`person`\",\n  
                \"attached\": null\n                }\n              ]\n            }\n          },\n          {\n            \
"finalizing_table_conditions\": [\n            ]\n          },\n          {\n            \"refine_plan\": [\n              {\n                \
"table\": \"`person`\"\n              }\n            ]\n          }\n        ]\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"join_execution\": {\n        \"select#\": 1,\n        \"steps\": [\n        ]\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}",
  0,
  0
]
```

And I want it to render something like this, where all newlines actually go to a newline:
[image]

But instead I get this, where the \n is just directly printed:
[image]

Is there anything I can do to make it output the way that I want? I have tested changing the trace variable to a simple 'hey \nhey' string, and that works fine, so it seems to be something about this complex string. The string is genereated by doing an Sql query using the MySql xdevapi, and converting to strings using Json.stringify(query, undefined,2).

Comment: It seems to me that you would need a textarea instead of a textfield. 

Or if you want the output to be indented just like in the picture maybe the best approach is to create an array of strings and separate them by a given criteria and use a map() function to print each line at a time in a textfield.

Comment: I am looking at vscode's generated html for the code editor as an example and they use a sequence of divs with span tags and inside, to indent, they use "&nbsp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the problem was the JSON itself included the linebreak character \n and also some escaped string quotes. The JSON.stringify() method then actually prints these characters. I solved it by adding `.replace(/\\n/g, '\n').replace(/\\"/g, '"')`. Not the most elegant solution, but  it gives me the output that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the problem that your variable is an array rather than a simple string like in your test ?

Edit: The problem seems to come from the JSON.stringify() part. If you JSON.stringify('\n'), the output will be an escaped '\n' and not an actual linebreak

Comment: It is a JSON array that has been stringified through the JSON.stringify() method. That should not be the problem.

Comment: Actually if you JSON.stringify('\n') the output will be an escaped '\n', meaning that you will see '\n' and not the actual linebreak. You can see this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6fdbgk94/10/)
In your example you could try to display trace[1] to test this.

Comment: Okay I see, the problem might be in the stringify part then. Will look into that.

Comment: Yep, can confirm that the raw result of the query contains the linebreaks, which is why they are just printed. Then the question is, is there a simple way to 'unescape' them?

Comment: I would just change the way you handle your input. If you know that it is an array containing strings you could just use the join method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join